# How do you nudge UV islands?

Tags: uv

When I want to move a large UV face, and position it sharply, there's the problem that the handle is in the center of the UV island box.

So if I zoom in to have the resolution to position it perfectly, the handle will fall outside the window.

Is there a way to make like in 3DS Max, where you can click on the polygon to drag the entire island, and not only the handle that lies in the center of it?

Comment: Press "g" to grab your selection?

Comment: Doh didn't think that would work in there too, as there's the handle... useless handle from now on I guess... except for showing you the rotation pivot.
Thank you! BTW add it as an answer so you get your deserved points!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the UV window the standard <kbd>g</kbd> works so you can grab the selection. The keys <kbd>r</kbd> and <kbd>s</kbd> also work to rotate and scale the selection. There is also a 2D version of the 3D cursor so you can set the origin of the transform.